# storing form data in session

Tags: php, forms, session

So i am trying to store my forms data in the session i was reading about it and this is what i have.

```
$submit = $_POST["submit"];

session_start();

if(isset($submit)){setsessionvar();} 


function setsessionvar() {


foreach($_POST as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {
    $_SESSION['form'][$fieldname] = $fieldvalue;
    }   
}

$textarea_value = $_SESSION['form']['textextarea'];

echo "Textarea contained the value: ".$textarea_value;
```

Now i understand this and it should work. My question is how will it work with checkbox and drop down?

I do not think it will effect drop downs as i am guessing it will only catch the selected one from the list, but with the checkbox it dumps an array from the form. so would the result be an array in an array? Or would it cycle through the checkbox array from the form and load the items in it individually?

Comment: You can also do `$_SESSION['form'] = $_POST` instead of looping through the array and assigning the values. Then all posted data will be assigned too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same only less code:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['form'] = $_POST;
}
```

If you have a checkbox array then it will be an array under the `$_SESSION['form']` array in either case.

Comment: so array in an array that is what i was thinking. so $textarray = $_SESSION['form']['textarray[1]']; to get it from the checkbox array position 1